# UTF-8 CSV import ok but after processing with utf-8 shapefile accent replaced by '?'

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins, qgis-2.18, utf-8

I m using QGIS 2.18

I export data from SQL Developer to a csv file with ";" as separator and with UTF-8 encoding.

Then, I have imported the csv with UTF-8 encoding. Accents were imported right. 
[image]

But after processing a join by attributes between CSV and a Shapefile with .cpg "UTF-8" the accents disappear:

[image]

What's the matter? Is it from ogr2ogr sub "processing" that does not support the accents?

Comment: Please specify exactly which tool was used for the join by attribute operation.

Comment: EDIT : In Modeler, i use field calculator to convert the floats number into integer  in the csv table then i can join on this new field the Shapefile where the numbers to join are integers. I see the problem appears at the Field calculator step. I just tested with a join with no match (because of float numbers) and the accents are ok

Comment: Thanks to @rjhale [This is a bug](https://twitter.com/rjhale/status/806859521331171328) There is a workaround but how could i implement it in models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me. Checked in 2.18.3

Change the Processing encoding in Advanced Settings 'System' to 'UTF-8' or any other encoding

[image: Processing Encoding]